# Нужно ли говорить о «чувстве языка» при изучении стилистики и правил письма?

Tags: грамотная-речь, общие-вопросы, интонация

**1. Мы не умеем строить предложения «по уму»**

Наша логика  в этой теме (в привычном ее понимании) кончается где-то на уровне **словосочетаний**, а дальше начинается ***Terra  incognita.*** Мы, носители языка,  не умеем строить предложения по логике, а делаем это **по интуиции**: выбираем порядок слов или меняем его, переходим от одного стиля речи к другому и т.д.  Но стоит обратиться  **к чистой логике**, как наша письменная речь уже выглядит неумелой, искусственной, безжизненной.

**2. О чувстве языка: чем его можно заменить**

Какое еще чувство языка, зачем нам эта **метафизика**? И эти интонационные **схемы** с палочками и стрелками – зачем они нам! Мы и так слышим  интонацию. А чувство языка **у писателей** – это их дело!  Пусть себе чувствуют, а мы… А мы будем **списывать** у них готовые решения. Все поставили здесь запятую, да и правила (как мы их понимаем!) вроде бы рекомендуют  – вот и мы **поставим ее тоже**. Будем как они,  будем как все!

**3. Надо ли развивать  чувство языка его носителям**

Чувство языка как **музыкальный** слух, оно дается от рождения. Но если музыкального слуха нет, то его можно развить, изучая теорию, играя гаммы. Вот и чувство языка **развивается**, если мы много читаем,  вслушиваемся в каждое слово. И когда рисуем схемы с палочками и стрелками, оно **развивается тоже**. И тогда не будет необходимости все делать по **общим** правилам письма, а появится возможность  учитывать **конкретику** каждого решения.

**Спасибо за ваши ответы.** С одной стороны,  вопрос дискуссионный, но в то же время он  важен для практики.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ касается **интонационного анализа**, который способствует развитию "чувства языка" и может удачно применяться при решении нестандартных задач с вариантами.

**Розенталь** говорит о влиянии интонации на постановку знаков, но **не раскрывает** эту тему полностью. Почему? Пользователи даже сейчас **не готовы** к такому анализу, а что тогда говорить о его времени, о его задачах. Надо было дать расшифровку кодекса правил 1956 года в базовом и всем доступном формате. Казалось, в современной действительности **многое должно измениться**, но вот не меняется…

**Как это объяснить?** Вот интересная статья на эту тему Маятники. Как освободиться от рабства  https://silmagor.livejournal.com/823.html

*Нас с детства приучали подчиняться чужой воле, выполнять обязанности, служить отечеству, семье, политической партии, фирме, государству, идее. Все эти **структуры** зарождаются и развиваются, когда отдельная группа людей начинает мыслить и действовать **в одном направлении**. Затем присоединяются новые люди, и структура разрастается, набирает силу, заставляет своих членов следовать установленным правилам и в конечном итоге может **подчинить себе** большие слои общества.*

*Но что стоит за всем этим на энергетическом уровне? **Структура возникает**, когда мысли группы людей направлены в одну сторону. В таком случае посреди океана энергии создается отдельная независимая энергоинформационная структура – **энергетический маятник**.*

*Если количество приверженцев маятника уменьшается, его колебания угасают. Когда приверженцев совсем не останется, маятник останавливается и как сущность умирает. **Главный отличительный признак** деструктивного маятника состоит в том, что он агрессивно стремится уничтожить другие маятники, чтобы перетянуть людей на свою сторону. Для этого он постоянно натравливает своих приверженцев на чужих: **«Мы такие, а они другие! Плохие!»** Новое, необычное, непонятное, всегда с трудом пробивает себе путь.*

*Бороться с маятником бесполезно.. это значит отдавать ему свою энергию. Первым и главнейшим условием успешной борьбы с маятником является **отказ** от борьбы с ним.*

**Как это применить в нашей теме?**  Не надо обращать внимания на тех, кто не хочет новых знаний, кто активно протестует против всего, что не является общепризнанным. Это бессмысленная трата энергии.  Но нужно **последовательно  идти тем путем**, который вы выбрали для себя, и нужно искать своих сторонников  Так по общеизвестным законам диалектики создаются **«новые структуры».**

Comment: Сначала надо доказать, что есть варианты, а потом уже использовать это. Очень важно! Вы нередко используете, когда возможен только один вариант (обычно по семантике).

Comment: А эту «интересную статью», её фрагмент, здесь приправленный выделениями, обязательно читать в таком виде? Иначе случится что-то неконтролируемое? Не доверяете...

Comment: Это ключевые слова с моей точки зрения, именно они нужны для моей темы. А любопытная  она с разных точек зрения. Я об этих энергетических маятниках часто встречаю разные материалы.

Comment: Если приводимый текст не имеет выделенных мест, а цитирующий выделяет слова на своё усмотрение, то надо ли информировать об этом своего читателя?

Comment: Может, и надо, но я не информирую... )) По-моему, и так видно, что это я подчеркиваю, а не автор.  Забота о читателях: просмотрел по диагонали текст и решил, надо ли его читать.